# Conditions to ensure that if every element of a finitely generated group $G$ of is of finite order, then $|G|< \infty$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

In general, it's not true that every element being of finite order with $G$ finitely generated is enough to ensure that $G$ is finite.

I made some observations:
**the first observation is incorrect. Maybe a different argument can be used?**

1. If $G$ is finitely presented, then the previous data is enough to ensure that $G$ is finite 
   since  for generators $\{a_i\}$ with order $n_i$, there should be a surjection $$\langle a_1, \dots a_n \mid a_1^{n_1}, \dots, a_n^{n_n}\rangle=H \to G$$
   by taking the quotient by the normal closure of further relations. Or, since all said conditions in $H$ are true in $G$ as well, we should be able to find tietze transformations that make this work.
2. If $G$ is abelian, we should also be good by the classification theorem.

Question: Are there conditions for which we can conclude that a finitely generated group where every element is of finite order, is finite.

Comment: Your group H on (1) is not finite.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez a critical error, I am too used to commutative things, sorry.

Comment: It is a long-standing open problem whether a finitely presented group in which all elements have finite order is necessarily finite. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78410

Comment: @DerekHolt  oh my. That is truly surprising.

Comment: What kind of groups are you looking for, there are many classes of groups where torsion implies finite (fg solvable, automatic groups are a couple examples)

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: @MoisheCohen sorry about that, you've caught me twice in one day. Paul Plummer, that constitutes a (partial) answer. Clearly, it is too hopeful for necessary+sufficient conditions, but I would be content knowing a few different types of groups.

Comment: I think it is basically hopeless to come up with a necessary and sufficient condition that is anything other than basically rephrasing the property

Comment: @PaulPlummer it looks like it. If you gave some classes of groups that have this property, I would accept the answer. Otherwise, this question should probably be closed, although I hesitate to delete it in case any others have this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't expect any necessary and sufficient condition that is anything other than restating the condition (could refine to bounded torsion).

There are many classes of group which are widely studied, where the infinite examples always have infinite order elements: acylicdrically hyperbolic groups, CAT(0) groups, automatic groups, fg elementary amenable groups... etc

An interesting non-example though is that amenable groups in general do have infinite finitely generated torsion examples, in particular [Grigorchuk groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grigorchuk_group) are torsion, although they don't have bounded torsion. I *think* it is open if there are bounded torsion examples in the class of finitely generated amenable groups.